# Alternatives to Hyper-V to run the Windows Phone emulator

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-8, windows-phone-8, hyper-v, windows-phone-8-emulator

I recently bought a Windows 8 laptop just for the sake of developing Windows Phone Apps. Mine is not a Pro version hence Hyper-V does not run. (I realized that Hyper-V needs WinPro after I bought the laptop).

I am not capable of upgrading to pro edition. Can anyone please suggest me any alternatives to Hyper-V where my emulator can run? Thanks.

Comment: I believe the only alternative available for you is deploying the apps to a real device

Comment: @Kookiz And that means I need to get a developer account right?

Comment: @Kookiz Can I use vmware? Is it possible?

Comment: I don't think that this is supported. Why do not upgrade to Windows 8 Pro? Maybe notebook manufacture has some discount prices for update?

Comment: @outcoldman No discounts. I have to pay the full price. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: vmware is a better to solve the problem

Comment: Have you checked out a hosted VM solution through Azure? It would probably be short term cheaper than upgrading.

Answer (score 4):

you can use a virtual machine to deploy windows phone 8 OS.
My laptop processor does not support hyper-v so, I've installed win phone 8 on a virtual machine.
I found this link helpful..
check it out: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WANk_XaovqM

Comment: This does work and it looks promising but there are two BIG problems that have not been solved: You cannot connect a guest vm as usb device. Even if you somehow manage to get the app deployed the phone is not activated for development.

Comment: The video link is broken anyway. So much for nothing, Microsoft!

Comment: Found a working tutorial here: https://www.realmtech.net/2016-02/windows-10-mobile-without-hyperv. Just tested on Windows 10 and it works!

Answer (score 3):

**You do not need an emulator to test your apps anymore**. I don´t know exactly when Microsoft changed their limitations, but you can **now register one phone** to your Microsoft Account **without a developer account**. When you downloaded the wp8 sdk (Microsoft Download Center - it includes an express version of VS 2012), under "All Apps" on your Windows 8 laptop, there´s "Windows Phone Developer Registration".

See the prerequisites of a windows phone registration here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769508%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

It must have been a short time they changed that, but I didn´t find an official statement about it...

I think they **also changed the limitations on devices with that account**: you could have registered up to five phones with a developer account, now those are only three.

Answer (score 2):

The Windows Phone 8 emulator is a special Hyper-V image. It cannot run on other virtualization technology.

Without the emulator, the only alternative option would be to use an actual device.

Comment: That's not true. It also works with Virtualbox [1]
and VMWare. The only issue I had so far is getting a network connection.

[1] http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WANk_XaovqM

Answer (score 0):

Disappointed by the requirement of the Windows 10 Mobile SDK for SLAT, I decided to try to find another way to kick off with W10M development.

Here's a solution to get the Windows 10 Mobile Emulator working on Windows 7, without Hyper-V, and without SLAT.

**1.** Kick off by installing Virtualbox

**2.** Download "Microsoft Emulator for Windows 10 Mobile" [(direct link)](http://download.microsoft.com/download/C/D/A/CDA171B9-A53D-4759-AB29-FD9C49876CD9/emulator/EmulatorSetup.exe)

**3.** Run the auto-downloader, and choose "for installation on a separate computer". It will download XDE and the Emulator image (about 1.5GB).

**4.** Under \Redistributable\1.0.0.0, run WindowsPhoneSDK-VHD.msi

**5.** Copy C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Emulation\Mobile\10.0.10586.0\flash.vhd to somewhere you have write permissions

**6.** Create a new Windows 8 VM in Virtualbox, and use the existing flash.vhd file as the drive.

**7.** Edit your Virtualbox VM before firing it up to the following settings:

- Memory: At least 1024MB
- Chipset: ICH9
- Enable IO APIC
- Enable absolute pointing device
- Enable PAE/NX
- VT-x and Nested Paging should already have been checked by default
- Network: Under Advanced, change Adapter Type to Intel Pro/1000 MT Desktop (82540EM)

**8.** Fire up the VM. It will complain, quite possibly the error "General failure - DON'T USE THIS!!!". OK-away any errors, and try again.

The Windows 10 Mobile Emulator booted in Virtualbox for me after the third attempt. Starts first go every time now!

Works on an Intel Core2Quad Q6600, under Windows 7.

[Source Website info](https://www.realmtech.net/2016-02/windows-10-mobile-without-hyperv)