# Visual Studio version, phone emulator without Hyper-V

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

Good day
I recently downloaded *Visual Studio 2013 Update 5*, and then realized that I needed Hyper-V to run the emulator. I can't afford to upgrade to Windows 8.1 Pro right now, so which version of visual studio would I have to install on my computer to be able to develop for windows phone 7 without Hyper-V.
And would I still be able to get it?(*Visual Studio 2013 Update 5* is the earliest version I'm seeing for download on the VS website)

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: I believe your question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/17124554/512365

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you can use Visual Studio 2010 and Windows Phone 7.5 SDK. The SDK includes emulator that is not a Hyper-V machine.

However, the WP 7.5 SDK is old, and I don’t think it’s still supported.

You should either upgrade to windows 8.1 pro (if you are a student, you may be able to get it free of charge) or use a real windows phone for debugging.