# How To Run Windows Phone Emulator 8.1 on Windows 8.1 OS without Windows 8.1 Pro OS Version?

Tags: mobile, windows-8, virtual-machine, windows

I have installed my PC windows 8.1 (Core) with Visual Studio Professional 2013

I am beginner to develop Windows Mobile App. When I run sample app it shows message:

> Windows Phone Emulator
>
> Unable to start the windows phone emulator Windows phone emulator
>   require Hyper-V Your computer is missing the following
>
> pre-requisites required to run Hyper-V
>   -Windows 8 Proffesional(64-bit)
>
> 0*80131500

How to run Windows Phone Emulator 8.1 using Windows 8.1 OS?  Any alternative solution available?

Thanks & Regards

Jejai

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alternatives to Hyper-V to run the Windows Phone emulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17124554/alternatives-to-hyper-v-to-run-the-windows-phone-emulator)

Answer (score -1):

You can run Visual Studio 2013 in your machine,no problem about the windows version.:)

Here is how to fix your error. :)

1.Goto Your BIOS settings.
2. Check for a setting called "Intel Virtualisation Technology".
I cant specify exactly where it is.But It must be there in the BIOS settings and it should have been disabled.
3.So you need to enable it.

If you can specify the model of your motherboard I can help you further. :)

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply mr.Janith Ganewatta  I have already  enabled  "Intel Virtualisation Technology"

Comment: Similar Problem  Given Link  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6948e9ae-2085-4030-baab-a8b60d6ed5bc/cant-start-the-windows-phone-emulator-requires-hyperv?forum=wptools

Comment: he uses Home/Core editon which doesn't support Hyper-V. The solution is to upgrade to Pro or unlock his phone and deploy the app every time to his phone and test it there.